# FixedWindowRollingPolicy and SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy triggering policy not working with logback 1.1.7

Tags: java, logback, rollingfileappender

here is my logback configuration, files are not getting archived even after exceeidng 2MB(maxfileSize).I am using 1.1.7 version of logback.Not sure what exactly is the problem.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="RFILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>../logs/esync.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss} %-5level %mdc %logger{60}::%M:%line -
                %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>../logs/archive/esync.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>


            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
<maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>

    </appender>

    <root level="${log.level:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="RFILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are still facing this issue, here I gathered the solution from loback site : http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-74
"Given that on some platforms computing file size is a relatively expensive operation, in the isTriggeringEvent method of SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy class we check for the file size only once every 16 calls. For long lived applications this is not a problem since it will eventually make 16 calls to isTriggeringEvent(). However, for short lived applications making few logging calls before shutting down, isTriggeringEvent () may never be called 16 times"

On these lines, to test my short lived application I set my thread to sleep for a while, this lead the log file to rolled-over with the set size.
My Code while logging the statement :

```
public class MyLoggingClass {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLoggingClass.class);

    public void method1() {

        for(int i=0; i<50;i++) {
            logger.debug("This is Debug Message : " + i);
            logger.info("This is Info Message : " + i);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

This created log files exactly with the set max size(i.e. 1KB in my case) and rolled over if the size limit exceed. I hope this does fix your problem too.